# If column of one row match column of another row then add

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I would like to sum numerical values listed in the columns of the table below based on entries that were given in the first column of the same table. The table content is as follows:

```
10,Mumbai,0,4,5,0,6,3,55,M
2,Mumbai,1,3,2,0,4,4,4,M
4,Chennai,5,6,7,8,9,0,6,F
```

The expected outcome is as follows (data is grouped by the 2nd and last columns):

```
12,Mumbai,1,7,7,0,10,7,59,M
4,Chennai,5,6,7,8,9,0,6,F
```

How can I use awk on Linux to get this output?

Comment: What had happened if the `M` at the end of the second row had been `F`?

Comment: Row will not get add

Comment: So the entries should be grouped on the 2nd and last fields together, not just the 2nd field?

Comment: Yes correct, we have to grouped 2nd and last column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    $2 != vals[2] {
        if ( NR>1 ) {
            prt()
        }
        split($0,vals)
        next
    }
    {
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            if ( $i+0 == $i ) {
                vals[i] += $i
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        prt()
    }
    function prt(    i) {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", vals[i], (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
' "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
12,Mumbai,1,7,7,0,10,7,59,M
4,Chennai,5,6,7,8,9,0,6,F
```

If your input file isn't already grouped by the 2nd field (as it is in the sample input you posted) then change this:

```
awk '...' "${@:--}"
```

to this:

```
sort -t',' -k2,2 "${@:--}" | awk '...'
```

Comment: Note that the user has confirmed that the data must be grouped by the 2ndand last field, not just the 2nd field.

Answer (score 0):

Using the 2<sup>nd</sup> column as the key and to keeping the order of the records when outputing, we could do.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '!seen[$2]++{ recNr++ }
{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
      if(i!=2 && i!=NF)
          sumCol[recNr, i, $2]+= $i
      else 
          sumCol[recNr, i, $2]= $i (i==NF?ORS:"")
}

END{ for (key in sumCol){
         if(sumCol[key]!=""){
             recNumbr++; sep=""
             split(key, tmp, SUBSEP)
             for(j=1; j<=NF; j++){
                 printf ("%s", sep sumCol[recNumbr, j, tmp[3]])
                 sep=OFS
                 delete sumCol[recNumbr, j, tmp[3]]
             }
         }
     }
}' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `datamash`:

```bash
$ datamash -s -t , groupby 2,10 sum 1,3-9 <file | datamash -t , cut 3,1,4-10,2
4,Chennai,5,6,7,8,9,0,6,F
12,Mumbai,1,7,7,0,10,7,59,M
```

This uses `datamash` to sum column 1 as well as columns 3 through to 9 while grouping the input by the combination of columns 2 and 10.

Since `datamash` outputs the grouping columns first in its output, we do a second pass through `datamash` to rearrange them in the original order.

The output is sorted on the grouping columns, which is why `Chennai` in outputted before `Mumbai`.  If the original data is already sorted, remove `-s` from the command.

Another example:

```bash
$ cat file
10,Mumbai,0,4,5,0,6,3,55,M
2,Mumbai,1,3,2,0,4,4,4,M
4,Chennai,5,6,7,8,9,0,6,F
4,Chennai,5,6,7,8,9,0,6,F
4,Chennai,5,6,7,8,9,0,6,M
```

```bash
$ datamash -s -t , groupby 2,10 sum 1,3-9 <file | datamash -t , cut 3,1,4-10,2
8,Chennai,10,12,14,16,18,0,12,F
4,Chennai,5,6,7,8,9,0,6,M
12,Mumbai,1,7,7,0,10,7,59,M
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my %class = lines.classify(*.split(",").[1, *-1].join("\t"), as => {$_.split(",").[ 0,2..*-2 ][*;*]});  \
            for %class.kv -> $k,$v {say $k => $v.elems > 1 ?? [Z+] $v<> !! $v[*;*]};'   file
```

The OP might want to consider a Perl-family language for this problem. Above represents but one approach using Raku. Briefly, `lines` are read in and `classify`ed on both the second column and last column (index `[1, *-1]` after `split`ting on commas). Column information in the classifier `key` is redundant if also left remaining in the `value`, so the `as` parameter is used to remove the two non-numeric `classify`ing columns from the `value` component. The data is stored in a hash, `%class`.

From here the `%class` pairs are separated into `kv` key/value components, the `key` is printed, and `value`s are tested using Raku's ternary operator to see if they contain more than one `elems` (elements). If more than one element is found, columns are summed and out`put` using `[Z+] $v<>` (decontainerized followed by element-wise addition). If only one element, the columns are out`put` with `$v[*;*]` (flattened only, no summing).

Sample Input:

```
10,Mumbai,0,4,5,0,6,3,55,M
2,Mumbai,1,3,2,0,4,4,4,M
4,Chennai,5,6,7,8,9,0,6,F
4,Chennai,5,6,7,8,9,0,6,F
4,Chennai,5,6,7,8,9,0,6,M
```

Sample Output (tab-separated `keys`):

```
Chennai M => (4 5 6 7 8 9 0 6)
Chennai F => (8 10 12 14 16 18 0 12)
Mumbai  M => (12 1 7 7 0 10 7 59)
```

Note, comma-separated output is of course possible in Raku, however for simplicity's sake the answer below still abstracts the two 'grouping' columns into the first and second columns:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my %class = lines.classify(*.split(",").[1, *-1].join(","), as => {$_.split(",").[ 0,2..*-2 ][*;*]});  \
            for %class.kv -> $k,$v {put $k ~","~ ($v.elems > 1 ?? [Z+] $v<> !! $v[*;*]).join(",")};'  file
Chennai,F,8,10,12,14,16,18,0,12
Mumbai,M,12,1,7,7,0,10,7,59
Chennai,M,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,6
```

Finally, thanks to @Kusalananda for providing a more extensive Sample Input dataset.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/classify
https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#index-entry-operator_ternary
https://raku.org